# Products import successully with dataflow profiles but won't show on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, dataflow, import-products

Magento Version 1.9.3.6

I am able to import products using Dataflow profiles successfully.

All Cache is disabled.
Tried re-index all after import.
but still products don't show up in frontend.

If I just click on edit and save the product, it just show up correctly.

So If I am importing 20 products, I have to click and save individually each one of them, to make it show in the frontend.

Cannot make out what else I am missing here.

Comment: can you please reindex and clear cache and check

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the fact that, your imported products are missing some important information. It could be the category, store view, stock / quantity and the visibility in the catalog.
While importing, make sure your products have proper values for the above mentioned factors.

Comment: had it been so, I just click on product edit in the grid and then save, the product shows fine after that. without making any changes.